# What is the most efficient way to expand a variadic template's values in a specific order?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I can currently do this:

```
template <std::size_t... Is, class... Ts>
decltype( auto ) custom_expand( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... args )
{
    auto tmp_tuple{ std::make_tuple( std::forward<Ts>( args )... ) };
    return std::make_tuple( std::move( std::get<Is>( tmp_tuple ) )... );
}
```

Calling the function...

```
custom_expand( std::index_sequence<1, 2, 0>{}, int{ 0 }, char{ 1 }, double{ 2 } );
```

...returns `std::tuple<char, double, int>` as expected. However, this requires constructing a temporary `std::tuple<>` and all that operation entails.

Is there a way that avoids a temporary `std::tuple<>` so that I don't have to pay for any copies/moves?

Comment: *"However, this requires constructing a temporary std::tuple<> and all that operation entails."* - did you quantify that with optimisation enabled on your compiler?

Comment: @TonyD I did not, thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid excess copies/moves, use `forward_as_tuple` for the temporary. That returns a tuple of references, which can be readily optimized away by any decent optimizer.

```
template <std::size_t... Is, class... Ts>
auto custom_expand( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... args )
{
    auto tmp_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Ts>( args )... );
    return std::make_tuple( std::get<Is>( std::move(tmp_tuple) )... );
}
```

Comment: Or just `auto` for short.